# Porque é que a palavra "raro" tem significado, em português, diferente de em espanhol?

Tags: significado, etimologia, vocabulário, diferenças, castelhano

A palavra *raro*, em português, significa *incomum*, enquanto que em espanhol significa *estranho*. Qual é a etimologia desta palavra, em ambas línguas?  Se têm a mesma origem, porque é que têm significados diferentes?

Answer (score 7):

**PORTUGUÊS (English follows)**

Etimologia:
Tanto em espanhol como em português, "raro" vem do latim *[rārus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rarus)*.

O significado é o mesmo ou semelhante em ambas as línguas.

Significado em Espanhol (fonte: [Real Academia Española](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=raro))

1. Que se comporta de uma maneira incomum.
2. Extraordinário, incomum ou infreqüente.
3. Limitados na sua classe ou espécie.
4. Ilustre, notável ou excelente em sua linha.
5. Extravagante de gênio ou comportamento, provável a tornar-se singular.
6. Referido principalmente de um gás rarefeito: Tendo baixa densidade e consistência.

Significado em Português (fonte: [Dicionário Eletrónico Estraviz](http://www.estraviz.org/raro))

1. Que não é ordinário: formosura rara. ≃ admirável, estranho, excelente, exímio
2. Que não é frequente: acontecimento raro. ≃ escasso, estranho, inaudito, insólito
3. Que existe em pequena quantidade no globo. ≃ escasso, estranho
4. Pouco denso. ≃ escasso, estranho
5. Que tem mérito extraordinário: meninha de talento raro. ≃ excelente, exímio, inaudito, insólito
6. Peça com orifícios que se adapta ao cano do regador para espalhar a água.

---

**ENGLISH**

Etimology:
Both in Spanish and Portuguese, *raro* comes from the Latin *[rārus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rarus)*

The meaning is the same or similar in both languages.

Meaning in Spanish (source: [Real Academia Española](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=raro))

1. That behaves in an unusual way.
2. Extraordinary, unusual or not common.
3. Limited in their class or kind.
4. Illustrious, outstanding or excellent in its line.
5. With extravagant genius or behavior, likely to be singled out.
6. Mainly  said about a rarefied gas: Having low density and consistency.

Meaning in Portuguese (source: [Electronic Dictionary Estraviz](http://www.estraviz.org/raro))

1. Not ordinary: *formosura rara. ≃ admirável, estranho, excelente, exímio*
2. Not common: *acontecimento raro. ≃ escasso, estranho, inaudito, insólito*
3. That there is a small amount on the globe. *≃ escasso, estranho*
4. Shortly dense. *≃ escasso, estranho*
5. What has extraordinary merit: *meninha de talento raro. ≃ excelente, exímio, inaudito, insólito*
6. Piece with holes that fits pipe watering can to spread the water.

---

Answer (score 4):

As palavras *incomum* e *estranho* são sinônimos, mesmo que a palavra *estranho* soe como algo pejorativo, não significa isto totalmente, assim como *incomum* também pode ser usado eventualmente para apontar algo fora do "normal".

Vendo o site http://sinonimos-online.com/incomum.html

### Sinônimos de incomum:

- incomum *[adjetivo]*

  (significa "raro")

  diferente, singular, *estranho*, curioso, chamativo, *aberrante*, *anormal*, *anômalo*, *bizarro*, *esquisito*, excepcional, extraordinário

Comment: Mais um caso como o do calão ;)

Answer (score 4):

Só para expandir a resposta do @Guilherme - a etimologia sugere que o significado *"infreqüente"* é mais antigo do que *"fora da norma"*.

> **ETIMOLOGIA**
>   lat. *rarus*,a,um "que apresenta intervalos ou interstícios, espaçado, poroso, esparso, pouco cerrado, pouco denso, ralo"
>
> Fonte: Dicionário de Português, Oxford University Press